# intersection of sets of the same measure

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that the elements of a set $A \subset [0, 1]$ have a property $\alpha$ and the elements of another set $B \subset [0, 1]$ have a property $\beta$, and that both sets have the measure $1$.

Then, is it necessarily true that their intersection $A \cap B$ has the measure $1$ and consists of elements which have both properties $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ?

Comment: Yes, though I don't really know what this "property" thing is all about.

Comment: In the first paragraph you said that the ***set*** $A$ has property $\alpha$ and the ***set*** $B$ has property $\beta$. But in the second paragraph you want the ***elements*** to have the properties $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Which is it?

Comment: Consider the integral $F(t) \equiv \int_{0}^{1}f(t, r) dr$, with $f \geq 0$. "If we know that $F(t) \leq 1$ for all real $t$, then what can we say about the local behavior of $f(t, r)$?"; this is the type of questions I have been thinking for a few days. One of the properties which elements of a set satisfy is, "there exists an $M > 0$ such that $f(t, r) \leq M$"; if its measure is not $1$, then $F(t) \leq 1$ no longer is satisfied (I guess?).

Comment: "Which is it?" To clarify, I want the elements of sets to have properties.

Comment: @Mr.SnowRemover Well if all elements of set $A$ have property $\alpha,$ and all of $B$ have property $\beta,$ then all elements of $A\cap B$ have property $\alpha$ and property $\beta,$ since they're all both in $A$ and $B.$ This very elementary compared to your question about the measure.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Oh, yes. Apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $I=[0,1]$ with measure $1$.

Then the complements of $A$ and $B$ ($I-A$ and $I-B$) each have measure $0$. Now $I-(A\cap B)=(I-A)\cup(I-B)$, so $\mu(I-(A\cap B))=\mu((I-A)\cup(I-B))\le\mu(I-A)+\mu(I-B)=0$.

Therefore $\mu(A\cap B)=1$.

[spaceisdarkgreen answered the other part of your question in a comment.]

Comment: Thanks. Since I am not familiar with measure theory, I wanted to make sure my guess is correct.